# Trapezium Midsegment Theorem

Tags: geometry

A question from an ACT Math test:

[image]

Please teach me a way to get the answer quickly, I must've missed some properties of trapezoid cause I can only think of making similar triangles to find the answer but I'll have to assume two unknown numbers, which is too time-consuming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Trapezoid Midsegment Theorem states that

> $ABCD$ is a trapezoid with $AB||CD$. $EF$ is a line connecting the midpoints of sides $AD$ and $BC$, that is $AE=ED$ and $BF=FC$. Then, $EF||DC$ and that $EF=\frac{1}{2}(AB+DC)$.
> [image]

For a proof of the theorem check [Trapezoid Midsegment Theorem Proof: Geometry Help](https://geometryhelp.net/trapezoid-midsegment-theorem/#:%7E:text=The%20triangle%20midsegment%20theorem%20states,length%20of%20the%20third%20side.).

Use this to go through the following solution:
$$\overline{EF}=\frac{\overline{BC}+\overline{AD}}{2}\Rightarrow \overline{AD}=38\mathrm{~inches},\\\overline{GH}=\frac{\overline{EF}+\overline{AD}}{2}=31.5\mathrm{~inches}.$$